# Illegal instruction (core dumped) while runing # rasa init cmd and unable to genrate a model or train it

Tags: init, coredump, python-3.10, rasa, illegal-instruction

I am using Python 3.10.5 and Rasa 3.6.19 in env. When I execute:

```
rasa init
```

this error occurred:

> Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
> Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()
> /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/shared/utils/validation.py:134: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
> import pkg_resources
> /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py:2868: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('google')`.
> Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
> declare_namespace(pkg)
> /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py:2868: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('mpl_toolkits')`.
> Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
> declare_namespace(pkg)
> /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py:2868: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('ruamel')`.
> Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
> declare_namespace(pkg)
> Welcome to Rasa!
>
> To get started quickly, an initial project will be created.
> If you need some help, check out the documentation at https://rasa.com/docs/rasa.
> Now let's start!
>
> ? Please enter a path where the project will be created [default: current directory]
> ? Directory '/mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/rasachatbot' is not empty. Continue? Yes
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/actions/actions.py -> ./actions
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/actions/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc -> ./actions/**pycache**
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/actions/**pycache**/actions.cpython-310.pyc -> ./actions/**pycache**
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/actions/**init**.py -> ./actions
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/endpoints.yml -> .
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/credentials.yml -> .
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/tests/test_stories.yml -> ./tests
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/data/rules.yml -> ./data
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/data/stories.yml -> ./data
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/data/nlu.yml -> ./data
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/domain.yml -> .
> 2024-03-20 14:45:47 INFO     root  - copying /mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/Maia_2/maia_2_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rasa/cli/initial_project/config.yml -> .
> Created project directory at '/mnt/837a55f3-96e7-4e14-8bba-9d93475fb8ae/PYTHON/rasachatbot'.
> Finished creating project structure.
> ? ? Do you want to train an initial model?  Yes
> Training an initial model...
> Illegal instruction (core dumped)

and a model is not generated. It happens every time I try to upgrade my package using pip, but nothing works. I expected to have default train model, as mention in Rasa manual, which I can then train later.

Answer (score 0):

First, also the reason for question downvote i believe, is - Follow the good practices while questioning/answering on the forum. Use code blocks, inline codes to properly present the code sections.

Nevertheless, your problem is due to library incompatibilities. Try Rasa 3.4 with python 3.8, they work fine together as far as i know.